# High power usage caused by network interface on Thinkpad T480

Tags: networking, network-manager, power-management, battery, thinkpad

I am having troubles with bad battery performance on Thinkpad T480 (i5-8350u, MX-150 all drivers purged).

Is there a way to improve the power consumption of the 'Network interface: enp0s31f6 (e1000e)' to get to a satisfying 6-7 hours of battery life (currently taking 6W at least - always). (Or at least remove the network interface from consuming power on demand if possible)

Can someone help?

Screenshot: [energy consumption t480](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCmjH.png)

Comment: If anyone is trying to fix this: I found out that the Thinkpad T480 is only certified for Ubuntu 16.04LTS. So everything works fine downgrading to it.